# Cannot seem to access ClassKit Catalog while testing Apple Schoolwork in development environment

Tags: ios

I have an app which integrates with Apple's ClassKit. I also intend to publish the Contexts using ClassKit Catalog API. As far as I can tell (but I'm not really sure with that), Schoolwork should be able to access the information from there.

However, I only see information, which is provided by apps stored locally on the device.

When Schoolwork starts, it says "iCloud Drive is off", although I enabled it in the settings.

When I create an assignment, it sometimes says, that an error occurred and it shows only locally available activities (<del>unfortunately I cannot reproduce that right now</del> "There was an issue with your connection. Showing Local Activities Only." is shown on gray background right under "App Activies" when adding an App Activity).

Does anybody know, whether I should be able to see / access the ClassKit Catalog data using a development environment in Schoolwork; and which steps I need do, in order to make it work? (So I can see the assignments for my app, when it is not installed on the device?)

---

EDIT:

Citation from Apple's docs: (source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/classkitcatalogapi/testing_your_classkit_catalog_implementation )

> Test Your Changes
>
> After uploading content to the development environment, you can
> inspect the changes. On an iOS device that you use for development,
> with the Schoolwork app installed, go to Settings > Developer, and
> choose ClassKit API. Screenshot of the Developer settings on an iPad
> with ClassKit API shown at the top.
>
> Then use the ClassKit Catalog Environment section to choose either the
> Production or Development environment. Screenshot of the ClassKit API
> developer settings on an iPad.
>
> When you choose Development, the Schoolwork app on that device shows
> you data you uploaded to the development environment instead of the
> production environment data.